# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'to_clipboard'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, clipboard

I run Windows 10 and have installed Python 3 through Anaconda3.  I use Jupyter Notebook.

I run the following command as usual (has run many times without a problem):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_clipboard()
```

As of a sudden this bizarre error message appeared:

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'to_clipboard'
```

I googled the error message, and following what I read I did the following:

1. Searched my C:\ drive for pandas.py files and I deleted them. This did not change anything.
2. Restarted my Jupyter Notebook.  Again this did not work.
3. Uninstalled pandas and reinstalled them through Anaconda.  Again the same behavior is persisting.

Comment: There is no pd.to_clipboard. It is defined on the objects: `df.to_clipboard()` for example. You might be confusing it with `pd.read_clipboard()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `to_clipboard()` copies the object to the system clipboard.

So if you hve a dataframe `df` you can use `df.to_clipboard()` (with optional parameters) if necessary.

The `pd` does in fact *not* have a `to_clipboard()` attribute/function.